# Arduino code for servo motor

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I have a servo motor and I want it to spin a certain amount of degrees when I press a button.
Currently the servos spins as long as I keep the button pushed. I also need to keep the button pushed for about half a second till the servo moves or the control LED lights up.
I want the servo to perform a spin of x degrees or x milliseconds when I push it, no matter how long you keep the button pushed, it should perform just that movement.
This is the code I have now:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;  

int LED = 13;
int BUTTON = 4;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
  myServo.attach(9);
}

void loop()
{
  if(digitalRead(BUTTON)==HIGH)
   {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    myServo.writeMicroseconds(1700);  // Counter clockwise
      delay(200); 
   }

  else
  {  myServo.writeMicroseconds(1500);  // Stop
     delay(200); 
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag that you set when the button is read as pressed for the first time, and unset it when no button press is read.

To check that the button has been pressed for a while, make a second call to the read function after some milliseconds and if it still is pressed, go on. There are more elegant solutions to this but they require use of interrupts.

```
...
int ButtonPressed = 0;
...
void loop()
{
    // Button pressed?
    if (digitalRead(BUTTON)==HIGH)
    {
        // Try again in a while
        delay_ms(500);
        // Still pressed?
        if (digitalRead(BUTTON)==HIGH)
        {
            // Has button been pressed previously?
            if ((ButtonPressed & (1<<BUTTON)) == 0)
            {
                // Yes
                ButtonPressed |= (1<<BUTTON);
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {  
        // Button has been released
        ButtonPressed &= ^(1<<BUTTON);
        ...
    }
}
```